# LinkedIn OAuth2 Gives Error Message "Your LinkedIn Network Will Be Back Soon". How do I get it to redirect to LinkedIn

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Try the following link. I will leave that Client ID in place for a month, then remove it.

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=77jkfibk9qc4qx&redirect_uri=https://data-ir.com/linkedin_redirected&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social

If you try it you will see the error message.

I tried this URL and it should redirect to LinkedIn so that the user can authorise the API access

I tried asking LinkedIn but they asked me to post here.